# Can I use Maneuvers out of combat?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle

Can you initiate a maneuver outside of combat? This is specifically about the Moment of Perfect Mind maneuver, which allows me to substitute my Will save for a concentration check. My GM feels that I should not be able to initiate it outside of combat, since it effectively grants me a Will save that is better than my best save.
I don't see why I should not be able to initiate it outside of combat. A Druid can Wildshape out of combat and a Wizard can still cast his spells whenever he wants. My Warblade should be no different.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Martial Maneuvers Are Usable Outside Combat

*Tome of Battle* puts no restrictions on using maneuvers outside of combat. The text does, however, put some restrictions on *recovering* maneuvers outside of combat. In the chapter Blade Magic in the section Recovering Expended Maneuvers under the heading End of an Encounter there's this text:

> In the case of a long, drawn-out series of fights, *or if an adept is out of combat entirely*, assume that if a character makes no attacks of any kind, initiates no new maneuvers, and is not targeted by any enemy attacks for 1 full minute, he can recover all expended maneuvers. If a character can’t avoid attacking or being attacked for 1 minute, he can’t automatically recover his maneuvers and must use special actions to do so instead. (40)

Emphasis mine. Those *special actions* are described in the same section, so, for example, a warblade recovering maneuvers this way recovers maneuvers more slowly than by using his special action but still might find this way useful if prevented from making melee attacks.

**Stances**
As an aside, in the chapter Blade Magic in the section Initiating Stances and Maneuvers there's this text:

> You can remain in a stance outside of combat situations, and you can enjoy its benefit while exploring or traveling. (38)

So this is pretty much unambiguous.

**The DM's Concern**
While the DM's concern is valid--it probably *is* easier for your character to get a better result on his Concentration skill check than it is on his normal Willpower saving throw--, abilities are *supposed* to do stuff. There'd be little sense in picking such a maneuver if it *didn't* do what it was supposed to do: give your character a better chance at making *one* successful Willpower saving throw, after which the maneuver must be recovered. If pressed, tell the DM your character must be targeted with effects requiring a Willpower saving throw *twice* in rapid succession, and the *second* effect will require your character to use his normal Willpower saving throw bonus. Foes will probably figure this out quickly in combat, and others will try to exploit your sometimes-weakened Willpower saving throw as your character's reputation for *momentarily* indomitable will grows.

Comment: Huh, I'd never seen that clause. Nice.